# C# lambda event handler into VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lambda, event-handling

I need to convert some `C#` code into `VB.NET`. How should the below lambda event handler be written in `VB.NET`?

```
item.PropertyChanged += Function(s, e)
                             If e.PropertyName = "SomeProperty" Then
                                  //do something
                             End If
                        End Function
```

Code converter tools do not provide any meaningful conversion for this.

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close this question on the grounds that it is "unclear". It seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say definitely since I'm not sure what the type of item is but I imagine this will work:

```
AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, Sub(s, e)
                                    If e.PropertyName = "SomeProperty" Then
                                       'do something
                                    End If
                                 End Sub
```

Comment: I was only looking for the correct syntax here, so item can be any object that has INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.